# data is not downloading from aws server using mobile data

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

i am developing an app in unity with backend aws server for phpmyadmin. It works fine when connected to wifi. But when i connect it with mobile data it does not download the data from server. Even it does not download the data when phone is connected with hotspot. I don't know what the problem  is, but in very trouble. Kindly help me. 
Also when i change the server to 000webhost it works fine with everything, but i don't want to use 000Webhost

Comment: Also when i change the server to 000webhost it works fine with everything, but i don't want to use 000Webhost.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the addition you made in the comment.

Comment: Are you running a webserver in AWS?

Comment: yes i am running aws server